# Cannot insert object inside a group in a runtime function

Tags: android, ios, iphone, lua, coronasdk

In my game I have to insert an object in a group in a runtime function, but the terminal returns

> Attempt to call method 'insert' (a nil value)

The code which is not working is:

```
function onCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
            if event.object1.myName == "ob1" and event.object2.myName == "spaceShip" then
                Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", onCollision )
                timer.cancel(tmrScore)
                gameOver.alpha = 1
                tapToReplay.alpha = 1
                replay.alpha = 0.01
                fade.alpha = 0
                timer.cancel(tmrIS)
                spaceShip.alpha = 1
                if(playEffects) then
                    media.playEventSound( "sounds/gameover.mp3" )
                    playEffects = false
                end
                speed = 0


                local matchScore = score.get()
                local bestScore = score.load()

                if (matchScore < bestScore) then

                    local best = display.newText("Best:", _W/2, 215, "PUSAB",      16)
                    best.alpha = 1
                    best:setFillColor(1, 0.5, 0)
                    localGroup:insert(best)

                    local scoreToBeat = display.newText(score.load(),   _W/2, 250, "PUSAB", 16)
                    scoreToBeat.alpha = 1
                    scoreToBeat:setFillColor(127, 255, 0)
                    localGroup:insert(scoreToBeat)

                else
                    print ("New Record!!")
                    score.save()
                    print (score.load())
                    best.alpha = 0
                    local bestScore = display.newText("New record!", _W/2, 215, "PUSAB", 16)
                    bestScore.alpha = 1
                    bestScore:setFillColor(255, 0, 0)
                end
            end




Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", onCollision )
```

and I get the error on `localGroup:insert(best)` and on `localGroup:insert(scoreToBeat)`

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your localGroup display group accessible to the onCollision event handler.

To do that, the simplest solution is the following:
Make the local group visible on the whole file scope. To do that you need to declare your localgroup variable before the collision function scope starts:

```
local localGroup = nil

function onCollision(event)
   etc
```

Once you have done that, if localGroup is a storyboard group, you will need to assign your group in your :createScene storyboard handler (if you are using storyboard) so that the display group will be visible inside onCollision:

```
-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    localGroup = self.view
```

If the localGroup variable isn't the storyboard group and you created one with display.newGroup() then you just have to declare it like this instead:

```
local localGroup = display.newGroup()

function onCollision(event)
   etc
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was that easy, it finally works! Thanks again!

Comment: No problem :)) If it helped you please feel free to select the answer as best answer ;)